# Css3 Animation with rotate

Tags: html, css

I am using a background to rotate globe. But it stop/jerk after some rotation. I am not sure where i am making mistake and why its jerking after some rotations.

Here is the code with fiddle

HTML

```
  <div id="earth">
  </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-color: black;
}

#earth {
width: 143px;
height: 143px;
background: url(http://www.noirextreme.com/digital/Earth-Color4096.jpg);border-radius: 50%;
background-size: 320px;
box-shadow: inset 1px 0 27px 1px rgb(5, 5, 5), inset -3px 0 5px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
-webkit-animation-name: rotate;
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-name: rotate;
-moz-animation-duration: 4s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-ms-animation-name: rotate;
-ms-animation-duration: 4s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: rotate;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
z-index: 9999;
position: relative;
margin-left: 52px;

}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
from { background-position-x: 0px; }
to { background-position-x: 210px; }
}


@-ms-keyframes rotate {
from { background-position-x: 0px; }
to { background-position-x: 210px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
from { background-position-x: 0px; }
to { background-position-x: 210px; }
}


@keyframes rotate {
from { background-position-x: 0px; }
to { background-position-x: 210px; }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k54QN/

Comment: nothing rotates on the JSfiddle in Firefox, although the globe image does display.

Comment: Good! I never know that code is not compatible with FFox, But its works in GC and jerks!

Comment: One day CSS will have constants. Deep in my heart I *know* it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited for 43px globe:

Match `background-size` like this:

```
#earth {
width: 43px;
height: 43px;
background-size: 86px, 43px;  //Height should match height of globe (unless you don't want to see the poles) and width should be 2x height

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  to { background-position: 86px 0px; } //Match Width
}


@-ms-keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  to { background-position: 86px 0px; } //Match Width
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  to { background-position: 86px 0px; } //Match Width
}


@keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  to { background-position: 86px 0px; } //Match Width
}
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k54QN/18/

Comment: It may just be a bit laggy since it's such a huge image – if you continue to watch for a few rotations, your computer gets better at it, and it become smooth.

Comment: No, Image was not the problem, The problem was mismatch between width and bg size. width 300 and bg size 299 fixed the issue.

Comment: That's what I was saying – see updated answer for a cleaner background-size (1/16th scale) and the matching width (needs to be double)

Comment: This is working well, But the actual width is 43px and height is 43 px of globe. So how can i set bg size to match this scale?

Comment: 43 is the actual width of what?

Comment: I mean, The W/H i am using for the globe is 43px. So How can i set bg size according to it?

Comment: Edited answer and fiddle for 43px globe

Comment: Double check that the fiddle matched what's posted – I was having trouble getting updates to take place... What's important is that the background image is scaled to match the size of the globe, and the width of the animation is twice the width of the background image

Comment: *Gah, I've had my height and width confused. The code is still right, but the comments are wrong, it's a 1:1 match with width (which just happens to be 2x height)

Answer (score 2):

Your "to" `background-position` should be equal to the width of the image.

Comment: I used the equal width and bg size but still same!

Comment: I did and the problem disappeared on IE11 and FF26.

Comment: Great! Yes That was the problem, dismatch in width and bg size, I match it closly and fixed :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Add this to #earth

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

It'll use the the GPU for hardware acceleration.

Comment: Nope! Its still jerking, Watch it for 3 or 4 sec, You will surly see that it jerks

Comment: Good idea, but the problem is just caused by a mismatch between backgound size and translation excursion, I think.

Comment: You are right! width 300px and bg size 299px worked fine and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position-x: 0px; }
  to { background-position-x: 590px; }
}


@-ms-keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position-x: 0px; }
  to { background-position-x: 590px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position-x: 0px; }
  to { background-position-x: 590px; }
}


@keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position-x: 0px; }
  to { background-position-x: 590px; }
}
```

Try changing the background-position-x from "TO", one thing that might be a problem is that it'll rotate faster, but then you just extend the animation time.

Comment: 590px is still jumpy – you need to match the size of the background image